# master-makefile

Tags: makefile

Hello I'd like to create a master file for 3 separated makefiles in 3 different directories. Makefiles work on their own, but not from a mastermakefile (below). After entering A directory, I get an error that: make: Circular A <- A dependency dropped.
make: `A' is up to date.

```
PROG = A B C
TRGTS = A B C

$(PROG): $(TRGTS)

all: $(TRGTS)

A:
    cd ./A ; make a

B:
    cd ./B ; make b

C: 
    cd ./C ; make c

clean:
    / rm -f *.o *~
    cd ./A ; make clean
    cd ./B ; make clean
    cd ./C ; make clean
```

Comment: PROG is the same as TRGTS but PROG depends upon TRGTS - is that reasonable?

Comment: `all` should normally be the first target in the makefile.  The actual first target is `A`; and you say 'build A by making sure that A, B and C are all up to date'...

Comment: Consider the wisdom enshrined in ['Recursive `make` Considered Harmful'](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/).  It isn't trivial to retrofit the techniques into a project, but it can be done (I've done it on a 20-directory project).  I've not done it on my main work projects, though (they're bigger by quite a margin, and the build system isn't clean enough yet to do this as well).

Comment: Hi, hm..... I did get that "build A by making sure that A, B and C are all up to date" where is that? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is almost the same as William answered, but without using 'for' loop statement.

```
subdirs := A B C

.PHONY: all $(subdirs)

all: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm rusty on makefiles and know for sure the following is not the best answer. But it might help for now...

```
TARGETS = A B C

.phoney: all
all:
    @for subdir in $(TARGETS); do \
      $(MAKE) -C $$subdir all || exit 1; \
    done
```

Note that the indents must use a TAB, not spaces

Comment: I used this solution for the clean target, complimenting Taizo Ito's answer.